# Setting vertically middle in writing-modes

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some text and `writing-mode: vertical-rl`. Now I want to this text be in the middle but `vertical-align: middle;` don't work even with setting `line-height`.

```css
.a{
      background-color: coral;
      writing-mode: vertical-lr;
      min-height: 10em;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="a">hiiiii<div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: ```writing-mode: vertical-lr``` will basically rotate your text in vertical top to bottom. If this is what you want then just add ```-webkit-``` to ```writing mode```.

Comment: @naser I'm added an answer below,don't forget to tick it if it's useful :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use **css3 flexbox** concept,add the following codes to your style sheet ,it works fine

```
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
```

I'm added the snippet below.

```css
.a{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      background-color: coral;
      writing-mode: vertical-lr;
      min-height: 10em;
      line-height: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="a">hiiiii<div>
```

Comment: Is there a solution for IE11 also?

Answer (score 5):

try using flexbox like this,

```css
.a{
      display:flex;
      background-color: coral;
      writing-mode: vertical-lr;
      min-height: 10em;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 2em;
      justify-content:center;
      width:2em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="a">hiiiii<div>
```