# Can't seem to get the text to the right without moving the "box" with it

Tags: html, css

I want a "button" that moves when you hoover on it and it goes to another page when you click on it. The problem is that the text is to the far left and out of the screen. (The top button is to the top, the right button is good; I won't include those but if you want them just ask).

When trying to get it to the right, it takes the whole "box" with it.

I've tried `float:right, left:x px, right:x px, text-align:right`.

I have no idea what more I can try.

```css
#sideNavLeft a {
  position: fixed;
  left: -100px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 9%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  top: -6px;
  bottom: -52px;
  background-color: #696969;
}

#sideNavLeft a:hover {
  left: 0;
}

.Links {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="sideNavLeft" onclick="location.href='Webshop.aspx';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <%-- Webshop --%>
      <a href="#" class="Links">WEBSHOP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text should be on the right side of the box, so on screen. Right now it's on the left side and only appears when hoovering on the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rotate text using `writing-mode`, vertical align and text align no longer work the same.

The easiest solution is to set your container to `display: flex` and to align it using either `align-items` (horizontal axis using `flex-start`, `center` or `flex-end`) or `justify-content` (vertical axis).

I used `transform: translateX()` instead of `left` for the sliding effect / animation for a **smoother animation**, read why [**here**](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108).

And finally I used a fixed width (pixels instead of percentages) for a better control of the amount of text showing in the sidebar (10% of a small screen won't show your text at all for example).

```css
#sideNavLeft a {
  position: fixed;
  
  top:-6px;
  bottom:-52px;
  
  padding: 1em;
  
  /* I would suggest using a fixed width to always have the same amount of text showing */
  /* width: 9%; */
  width: 160px;
  
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #696969;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  /* Used transform instead of 'left' for a smoother animation */
  /* If you want to use a percentage width, use percentage here as well */
  transform: translateX(-90px);
  transition: 0.3s;
  
  /* Used flexbox to be able to align the text to the right side */
  display: flex;
  
  /* Optional : centering the text along the vertical axis */
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* Aligns the text to the right of its flexbox container */
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#sideNavLeft a:hover {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.Links {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    text-orientation: upright;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="sideNavLeft" onclick="location.href='We`enter code here`bshop.aspx';" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <a href="#" class="Links">WEBSHOP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS : A simple research would have helped you find the answer, see : 
[Setting vertically middle in writing-modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356769/setting-vertically-middle-in-writing-modes) or [Align right with "writing-mode: vertical-lr" in a fixed width container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263612/align-right-with-writing-mode-vertical-lr-in-a-fixed-width-container)